# When updating element ,which default value false or null, error occurs TypeError: Cannot read property 'exvariable' of null

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am working on nodejs express with mongoose. Every user has such as `exvariable` which controls permission to have `exvariabletext`.

My user model schema `exvariable` and `exvariabletext`;
exvariable : {type:Boolean,default:false},
exvariabletext:{type:String,default:null}

When I am trying to find user and check `if(user.exvariable === false)`, I am getting an Error such like that 
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'exvariable' of null. So I can't use the default value and update it.

I have tried to change the default value in schema and control in nodejs syntax but couldn't pass the error and I want to understand the logic.

And my code like this;

```
router.post("/setexvariable",(req,res)=>{
    
    User.findById(req.params.id,(err,user)=>{
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
            req.flash("error","Oops, try again ");
            res.redirect("back");
        }
        
        if(user.exvariable == false){
            user.exvariable=true;
            user.exvariabletext=req.body.text;
            user.save();
            req.flash("success","Welcome ");
            res.redirect("/somewhere",{user:user});
        }else{
            req.flash("error","You already has a exvariable ");
            res.redirect("back");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the `id` parameter in your route to be able to access it with `req.params.id`. In your code, `req.params.id` is `undefined`, so your query returns `null`.

You should have something like `router.post("/setexvariable/:id", (req, res) => {...})`. More on route params in [Express's documentation](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html).

Comment: Thank you vpalmerini, I didn't use specific route for this post request but old habits. I change `req.params.id` to `req.user.id` (this request defined after authentication so I have user session) then I could reach user and its properties. Thanks again.

Comment: great! glad to help